# Cant break loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops

So I'm just starting to learn python by creating a simple word game. Currently I am stuck on breaking the loop when entering "exit". Not sure what exactly I need to do to make it work. I've gone through some other posts but don't see any that really apply to what I want, unless I'm just not seeing it. Which could easily be just me. Any advice on any of this would be much appreciated, Thanks.

```
# Biggining of RPG
# Get users name
def name():
    input("Hi, what's your name?")
    if len(name) < 1: #Checks to see if user entered a name or not.
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Could you say it again?")
    else:
        print("Hello, ", + name + ", glad to meet you!")

# Directions
def showInstructions():
    # Print main menu and commands
    print("Time to start. You enter the Foyer"
          "Commands:"
          "'go [direction]'")

def showstatus():
    # SHows the current status
    print("**************************************")
    print("You're in the " + rooms[currentRoom]["name"])
    print("What do you do?")
    print("**************************************")

# Rooms
rooms ={
            1:  {"name": "Foyer",
                 "north":   2},
            2:  {"name": "Hallway",
                 "east": 3,
                 "west": 4,
                 },
            3:  {"name":    "Pit"},
            4:  {"name":    "Closet"}
        }

# start in room 1
currentRoom = 1

showInstructions()

#Loop forever
while True:

    showstatus()

    #Get the players noex 'move'
    #.split() breaks it up into a list array
    #IE. typing 'go east' would give the list:
    #['go', 'east']
    move = input(">").lower().split()

    #if they type 'go' first
    if move[0] == "go":
        #check that theyre allowed wherever they want to go
        if move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
            #set current room to the new room
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][move[1]]
        # Leaves the game
        if move == 'exit':
            break
            print("Goodbye, " + name)

        #there is no door (link) to the new room
        else:
            print("Thats a wall!!")
```

Comment: It seems to me a little bit odd that move[0] might be equal to "go" while move is equal to "exit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected some things and it works as you expected. The exit clause was badly indented, you had some syntax error in the name function and you didnt call the name input. Hope it helps.

I replaced the single quote from the last line by double quote for consistency only, it has the same meaning in python.

Also, you were comparing `move` to `"exit"` but you used `split` on your input so it is now stored in a list, so you had to check `move[0]`.

```
# Biggining of RPG
# Get users name
def name():
    name = input("Hi, what's your name?")
    if len(name) < 1: #Checks to see if user entered a name or not.
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Could you say it again?")
    else:
        print("Hello, " + name + ", glad to meet you!")
    return name

# Directions
def showInstructions():
    # Print main menu and commands
    print("Time to start. You enter the Foyer"
          "Commands:"
          "'go [direction]'")

def showstatus():
    # SHows the current status
    print("**************************************")
    print("You're in the " + rooms[currentRoom]["name"])
    print("What do you do?")
    print("**************************************")

# Rooms
rooms ={
            1:  {"name": "Foyer",
                 "north":   2},
            2:  {"name": "Hallway",
                 "east": 3,
                 "west": 4,
                 },
            3:  {"name":    "Pit"},
            4:  {"name":    "Closet"}
        }

# start in room 1
currentRoom = 1

name = name()

showInstructions()

#Loop forever
while True:

    showstatus()

    #Get the players noex 'move'
    #.split() breaks it up into a list array
    #IE. typing 'go east' would give the list:
    #['go', 'east']
    move = input(">").lower().split()
    print(move)

    #if they type 'go' first
    if move[0] == "go":
        #check that theyre allowed wherever they want to go
        if move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
            #set current room to the new room
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][move[1]]

        #there is no door (link) to the new room
        else:
            print("Thats a wall!!")
    # Leaves the game
    if move[0] == "exit":
        print("Goodbye, " + name)
        break
```